# Saving / embedding associated form types

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have 2 Entities `User` and `Member`

The `User` has all of the normal stuff associated (username, password, email)

The `Member` has some other fields, including, `First Name`, `Last Name`, `Age` etc

I'm trying to create a new `Member` and to display a form with both the `User` fields and the `Member` fields.

I currently have the following:

**User.php**

```
$protected $username;
$protected $email;


/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="BM\UserBundle\Entity\Member", mappedBy="user")
*/
protected $member;
```

**Member.php**

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BM\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="member")
 */
 protected $user;
```

I have 2 form types as well:

**MemberType.php**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('user', new UserType())
        ->add('firstname')
        ->add('lastname')
        ->add('age')
    ;
}

public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
{
    return array(
        'data_class' => 'BM\UserBundle\Entity\User'
    );
}
```

**UserType.php**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $builder
        ->add('username')
        ->add('email')
        ->add('password')
    ;
}


public function getName()
{
    return 'user';
}
```

When I refresh the page where the form is rendered, I get the following error:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to BM\UserBundle\Entity\Member::setUser() must be an instance of BM\UserBundle\Entity\User, array given, called in /var/www/proj/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/PropertyAccess/PropertyAccessor.php on line 345 and defined in /var/www/proj/src/BM/UserBundle/Entity/Member.php line 259

Line 259 is:

```
public function setUser(\BM\UserBundle\Entity\User $user = null)
```

Am I approaching this the right way?

EDIT:

MemberController.php

```
$member = new Member();
    $form = $this->createForm(new MemberType(), $member);

    if($request->isMethod('post')) {
        $form->submit($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $em->persist($member);
            $em->flush();

            $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Member has been saved');
        } else {
             $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('error', 'Could not save the member');
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try in this way

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $builder
        ->add('user', new UserType())
        ->add('firstname')
        ->add('lastname')
        ->add('age')
    ;
}

public function setDefaultOptions(array $options)
{
    return array(
        'data_class' => 'BM\UserBundle\Entity\Member'
    );
}


# UserType.php #

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $builder
        ->add('username')
        ->add('email')
        ->add('password')
    ;
}

public function setDefaultOptions(array $options)
{
    return array(
        'data_class' => 'BM\UserBundle\Entity\User'
    );
}
```

Take a look the documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can now embed the `user` form. But I still get the same error when trying to save the form.

Comment: How do you print the form?

Comment: try to switch mappedBy and inversedBy in your annotations (entity file)

Comment: I'm using `$form->createView()` and then using `form_row(form.name) }}` etc

Comment: Are you using {{ form_widget(form.user) }} for the embedded form?

Comment: Yes. Well `form.user.username`, `form.user.password` etc

Comment: Are you using getDefaultOptions method on the User Type? Is on the answer

Comment: Yes I am. I can send over the controller as well if that helps? I haven't switched the `inversedBy` because i don't want a `member_id` in the `users` table

Comment: It is right... I think your error is on the form types... take a look on your generated html. The embed form have the returned getName method of the UserType (like user['username']) on the input names?

Comment: I have things like `member[user][username]` (UserType) and `member[address1]` (MemberType)

Comment: Instead of `getDefaultOptions` I used `setDefaultOptions` which seemed to work